# serialize derived class member using XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have WSDL service class in which I would like to add extra properties. When I am trying to deserialize my derived class its giving error **"You need to add XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute to the 'ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction' member."**

Here is the code I wrote on top of service classes. (`executeCreatePaperClipTransaction` & `CreatePaperClipTransactionType` are classes from proxy object)

```
namespace MyProject.DTO
{
    [XmlType("executeCreatePaperClipTransaction")]
    public partial class CustomExecuteCreatePaperClipTransaction : executeCreatePaperClipTransaction
    {
        [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        [XmlElement("CreatePaperClipTransaction")]
        public CustomCreatePaperClipTransactionType ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction { get; set; }        
    }    

    public partial class CustomCreatePaperClipTransactionType : CreatePaperClipTransactionType
    {
        [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public executeCreateLoanIncrease ObjLoanIncreaseRequest { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]
        public executeCreateFreeFormEventFeePayment ObjFreeFormEventFeePaymentRequest { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

When I remove `[XmlElement("CreatePaperClipTransaction")]` line, its working fine. But in the seralized xml i want tag name to be `CreatePaperClipTransaction` and not `ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction`

I went through this answer but I am not sure how can i implement in my case https://stackoverflow.com/a/20379038/1169180

Comment: Why do you have two `[XmlElement]` attributes attached to the `ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction` property?  Is your problem that there could be two different elements names present in the XML, `<CreatePaperClipTransaction>` and `<ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction>`, and you want to bind both of them to the `ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction` property?  Also, your code doesn't compile due to missing base types.  Can you please add them as well as a sample of XML to be deserialized, and so extend your question to a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding two separate [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attributes to your `ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction` property, you should add one single attribute with all necessary information:

```
[XmlType("executeCreatePaperClipTransaction")]
public partial class CustomExecuteCreatePaperClipTransaction : executeCreatePaperClipTransaction
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CreatePaperClipTransaction", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public CustomCreatePaperClipTransactionType ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction { get; set; }        
}
```

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kTWRRR).

When you add multiple `[XmlElement]` attributes to a property, you are informing `XmlSerializer` that *multiple different XML element names* should be bound to the same property, for instance because the property value is polymorphic:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
}

public class RootObject
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "BaseClassProperty", Type = typeof(BaseClass))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DerivedClassProperty", Type = typeof(DerivedClass))]
    public BaseClass Property { get; set; }
}
```

In the example above, if the `Property` is assigned a `DerivedClass` value, the following XML will be generated:

```
<RootObject>
  <DerivedClassProperty />
</RootObject>
```

That doesn't seem to apply here.  You just want to bind your property to the XML element name `<CreatePaperClipTransaction>`.